# Bootstrap Modal Window not recognize all the variations of YouTube URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

On the Internet I found a jQuery code that works very well to open YouTube video in modal form. I change some dteails and everything was fine until I realized that do not recognize all the variations of YouTube URLs.

All I need is to extract the YouTube ID and put it in the right place. I wrote a regex and combined several versions but does not work with every URL.

This is my code:

```
$('a[href^="https://www.youtu"]').on('click', function(e){

        var YouTube=$(this).attr('href').replace(/feature=player_embedded[&\w]*(?!['"][^<>]*>|<\/a>)/ig, "").replace(";", "");  // replace player_embedded
            preg=/(?:http|https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com(?:\/embed\/|\/v\/|\/watch\?v=))([\w\-]{10,12})\b[?=&\w]*(?!['"][^<>]*>|<\/a>)/ig,
            youtubeID=YouTube.replace(preg, '$1');
        if (youtubeID!="" && (YouTube.indexOf('v') > -1 || YouTube.indexOf('embed') > -1))
        {
            // Prevent opening of external page
            e.preventDefault();
            // Variables for iFrame code. Width and height from data attributes, else use default.
            var width = $(window).width(),
                vidWidth = 800, // default
                vidHeight = 450; // default
            if ( $(this).attr('data-width') ) { vidWidth = parseInt($(this).attr('data-width')); }
            if ( $(this).attr('data-height') ) { vidHeight = parseInt($(this).attr('data-height')); }
            // responsive debug
            var vidWidth =  (width>vidWidth?800:(width-60));
            var iFrameCode = '<div class="video-container"><iframe width="' + vidWidth + '" height="'+ vidHeight +'" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ youtubeID +'?controls=0&autohide=1&autoplay=1&iv_load_policy=3&theme=light&rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>';

            // Replace Modal HTML with iFrame Embed
            $('#mediaModal .modal-body').html(iFrameCode);
            // Set new width of modal window, based on dynamic video content
            $('#mediaModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
                // Add video width to left and right padding, to get new width of modal window
                var modalBody = $(this).find('.modal-body'),
                    modalDialog = $(this).find('.modal-dialog'),
                    newModalWidth = vidWidth + parseInt(modalBody.css("padding-left")) + parseInt(modalBody.css("padding-right"));
                newModalWidth += parseInt(modalDialog.css("padding-left")) + parseInt(modalDialog.css("padding-right"));
                newModalWidth += 'px';
                // Set width of modal (Bootstrap 3.0)
                $(this).find('.modal-dialog').css('width', newModalWidth);
            });

            // Open Modal
            $('#mediaModal').modal();
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are other users entering said YouTube URLs, or just you?

Comment: It is expected that around 21000 users will post own YouTube URLs. I'm changing one of my old CMS that has around 19,000 YouTube entries in the database what users posed on own profiles. Earlier I used PHP for this and it was all static. It's now all dynamic on Bootstrap, AJAX and jQuery. For these things I want to avoid php and static approach. Thanks!